# A config problem related to not finding __dirname in react native

Tags: react-native

Code:(metro.config.js)
`const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config');

const DefaultConfig = getDefaultConfig('__dirname');
DefaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push('cjs');

module.exports = defaultConfig;`

Error:
`ConfigError: The expected package.json path: __dirname/package.json does not exist`

const DefaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
DefaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push('cjs');

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove string literals from __dirname!

```
const DefaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname); 
DefaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push('cjs');

module.exports = defaultConfig;
```